# How do I keep RecipientTime when executing MailItem.Move in an Outlook macro?

Tags: vba, outlook

In an Outlook 2003 macro; Is there a way to move a message between folders without changing the ReceivedTime-header?

I currently use the method `MailItem.Move`. But that automatically sets the `ReceivedTime` property to the current time, which isn't really what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried moving a mailitem from my inbox to the deleted items folder, and it seems to have kept the receivedtime without a problem...

You may want to try using the MailItem.copy function and moving the resulting mailitem object, but like I said I'm not seeing the same problem...

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Do an item.Save() and then do item.Move(), It will stamp current timestamp.